# Different facet prefix for different facet fields in SOLR

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I am using SOLR v7+ and trying to figure out how to specify a particular facet prefix for a particular facet field. Something like-

```
(facet.field=FIELD1 & facet.prefix=PREF1) AND (facet.field=FIELD2 & facet.prefix=PREF2)
```

So FIELD1 should contain prefix PREF1 and not PREF2, while FIELD2 should contain prefix PREF2 and not PREF1.

From [this link](https://grokbase.com/t/lucene/solr-user/08cvjmdbh7/issues-with-facet-prefix-multiple-facet-field), I tried this - `f.<fieldName>.<originalParam>=<value>` to solve my problem, it is not working. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Giving facet specific options through `f.field.facet.<param>` should work. The full syntax to get what you're asking for above, as URL parameters, would be:

```
facet.field=FIELD1&f.FIELD1.facet.prefix=PREF1&facet.field=FIELD2&f.FIELD2.facet.prefix=PREF2
```

Make sure to use the correct case for your field parameters, and there should be no `AND` anywhere - one `facet.field` parameter pr. field you want your facets for.